# ArgumentError, wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, devise, argument-error

I'm getting the error

```
ArgumentError in PagesController#home, wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

but I don't know why.  I have a `Users` model from Devise, and a `Dplan` model, where dplan `belongs_to :user` and a user `has_many :dplans`.  I'm trying to set up my site so that you can create a new dplan on the home page.  My home page view is this:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
<h1>Hello <%= current_user.name %>! <h1>

<%= form_for @dplan do |f|%>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.text_area :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
    </div>
<% end %>

<% else %>
<h1>DPlanner</h1>
<p>
    This is the home page for DPlanner.
</p>

<%= link_to "Sign up now!", new_user_registration_path, :class =>   "signup_button round" %>
<% end %>
```

This is dplans_controller.rb:

```
class DplansController < ApplicationController

  def create
      @dplan = current_user.dplans.build(params[:dplan])
      if @dplan.save
          flash[:success]="Dplan created!"
          redirect_to root_path
      else
          render 'pages/home'
      end 
  end 

  def destroy
  end 

end
```

And here is pages_controller.rb:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

    def home
        @title = "Home"
        @dplan = Dplan.new if user_signed_in?
    end

end
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error message - the only argument needed on the page is dplan, which I define in the pages controller.  Help!

Here is dplan.rb:

```
class Dplan < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name

    belongs_to :user

    validates :name, :presence=>true, :length => { maximum => 30 }
    validates :user_id, :presence =>true

end
```

Comment: It looks like the constructor for Dplan takes an argument.  Can you include the Dplan class.

Comment: If I comment out the 2 validates line, I get an error that says `NoMethodError in Pages#home, undefined method `dplans_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000101c45f20>:0x00000101c42320>` It looks like it has a problem with the `@dplan` in the line `form_for @dplan do...` in the home view.  Is there something wrong with the line `@dplan=Dplan.new` in the `pages_controller`?

Comment: i think the problem in #home is that @dplan is only defined if the user is signed in. what happens if the user isnt?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when using Devise + Omniauth and symptoms included:

1. there was no application trace whatsoever
2. it wouldn't go away even if my controller method was empty.
3. other controllers worked just fine

it turned out to be some sort of name collision that went away when I renamed my method and controller. For example:

`Invites#process` Error (1 for 0) 
`Invitations#process` --> Error (1 for 0) 
`Friends#Add` --> No Error!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, i also used the reserved keyword process and ran into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `user_signed_in?` with `current_user`. Or try to add `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in `application_controller.rb` to avoid if statement in your controller.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The error occurs in `PagesController#home`, not in `DplansController#create`.

Comment: Kishie, thank you for your answer, but it didn't work.  Mischa's right, the error is in `PagesController#home`, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Figured it out!  I was missing `resources :dplans` in `routes.rb`.  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out, I was missing `resources :dplans` in routes.rb. Thanks for all your help!